# how to do a live search form ModelChoiceField

Tags: django

how to do a live search in a ModelChoiceField form in the template html ... i write for example a number and a i will get just the data that have that number 
i am using django 1.9

models.py

```
class Suivre(models.Model):
formationffF=models.ForeignKey(FormationDispo,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
numcniF=models.ForeignKey(Personne,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
session = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

form.py

```
class Ajout3 (forms.Form):
numcniF=forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Personne.objects.all().order_by('-time'))
formationf =forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=FormationDispo.objects.all().order_by('time') )
session = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.TextInput())
```

tamplate.html

```
<form method="post">
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% csrf_token %}
{{con|crispy}}
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" > SAVE</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use [django-admin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/) and [ajax_select](https://github.com/crucialfelix/django-ajax-selects)

Create a file called admin.py in your app.

## admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from myproject.myapp.models import Suivre
from ajax_select import make_ajax_form

# creates model-centric interface where trusted users can manage content on your site. 
class SuivreAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Suivre
    form = make_ajax_form(
        Suivre,
        {
            'numcniF': 'all_personne',  # ForeignKeyField
             'formationf':'all_formationdispo'
        })

# registers admin
admin.site.register(Suivre, SuivreAdmin)
```

Notice that I am using [ajax_select](https://github.com/crucialfelix/django-ajax-selects) library which will create interface shown in below image.
 [image: ajax select]

Install ajax_select:

```
pip install django-ajax-selects
```

Add the app:

## settings.py

```
# settings.py
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'ajax_select',  # <-   add the app
    ...
)
AJAX_LOOKUP_CHANNELS = {
    'all_formationdispo': {
        'model': 'app.FormationDispo',
        'search_field': 'name'
    },
    'all_personne': {
        'model': 'app. Personne',
        'search_field': 'name'
    },
  }
```

Include the urls in your project:

## urls.py

```
# urls.py
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from ajax_select import urls as ajax_select_urls

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = [

    # place it at whatever base url you like
    url(r'^ajax_select/', include(ajax_select_urls)),
```

Comment: it's worked in the admin page thanks..but how to do that in the html page ?